# How to get current date on page load using JQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi all i am new to JQuery UI, i know how to get current date on page load using JQuery date picker, but i am not able to do same thing in this code.

Using this we can get current date on page load.

```
$(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date);
    });
```

But i want same this functionality with persisting of the below one how can i gett that using below code.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

instead of your first JavaScript code line after the script tag.
Otherwise the functions load before the elements are created.
In general you should put your jQuery code infront of you closing body tag.